# From Ubuntu Desktop with touch enabled to Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I already port a tablet to boot up Ubuntu Desktop Trusty with touch enabled and can do gestures. Now I want to somehow change from the Desktop GUI to something that look like Ubuntu Touch.  Doesn't make sense to run desktop GUI on tablet. Some questions:

- Looked over porting guide on Ubuntu Touch but it requires Android but
  why?
- Is there any way to run Ubuntu Touch without Android HAL?
- Or is there some sort of Ubuntu Touch emulator that you run on the
  desktop?